# Uninstalled system applications appear after reboot on HTC Desire X

Tags: applications, storage, htc-desire, uninstallation

I have tried a lot of things which mentioned in different forums such as:

- delete using root ES File Explorer.
- delete apk files from `/system/app`.
- clear Dalvik cache after uninstall (manually removing `/data/dalvik-cache` and `/cache/dalvik-cache` and using CWM recovery.
- all mentioned earlier together several times.
- Even reinstall ROM wiping data/factory reset and clearing Dalvik cache using recovery.

But no result. And  I get something like this on startup if I clear Dalvik 
 cache:
[image]
So there is a location from where OS gets these apps, isn't it? How can I get rid of these redundant apps?

**Update:**

Here a link where I downloaded ROM: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2249760

Comment: Those sounds like malwares. They usually get rid of by flashing the whole data and system partitions. Try find a RUU file and flash your phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling S-OFF on my device. Here more details https://androidforums.com/threads/uninstalled-system-applications-appear-after-reboot-on-htc-desire-x.1178166/#post-7596175

Comment: Please include the link's relevant info in your answer, as links tend to become invalid over time.